# How to print the unicode character '৷' in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

I am trying to print this `৷` particular unicode in bengali language in file the hex code for `৷` is `09F7`

```
outFileFd=open('File','wb+')
txt="৷"
outFileFd.write(txt.encode('utf-8')
outFileFd.close()
```

I get this error message:

```
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe0' in file ./p.py on line 3, but no
encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details.
```

Please suggest some solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several problems:

1. Python does not accept non-ascii characters in the source file if you don't provide encoding. You can fix this by either:

   1. Declaring the encoding (see [PEP-0263](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/)).

      I usually prefer to declare encoding by ensuring the source file starts with appropriate byte order mark except on `#!` scripts where it would conflict with the `#!` mark.
   2. Using escape sequences:

      ```
      txt = "\xe0\xa7\xb7"
      ```

      of course you can use unicode escape with unicode string (see below) like

      ```
      txt = u"\u09f7"
      ```
2. In python 2, plain strings are byte-oriented. So already in the encoding the source is in. You either:

   1. Need to declare the string unicode (python will convert it from the source encoding of utf-8) and call the `.encode('utf-8')`:

      ```
      txt = u"৷"
      outFileFd.write(txt.encode('utf-8'))
      ```
   2. *Not* call `.encode('utf-8')`, because the string is already utf-8.

      ```
      txt = "৷"
      outFileFd.write(txt)
      ```

   If you call `.encode` on a non-unicode string, it will raise an exception because it will try to implicitly convert the string to unicode and explicitly back, but the implicit conversion only works on ascii strings and yours is not.

   Note that this is where python 2 and 3 differ. In python 3 unprefixed strings are unicode and byte strings are prefixed with `b`.

Answer (score 3):

Since you know the codepoint number for the character you want to write, you can use a `\u` escape in a Unicode string:

```
txt=u"\u09F7"
with open('File','wb+') as outFile:
    outFile.write(txt.encode('utf-8'))
```

Alternatively, put an encoding directive at the top of the file:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
```

and change `txt="৷"` to `txt=u"৷"`, and everything should Just Work.  (In a module, or any other context where you don't need the `#!` line, the `# -*- encoding:` line should be the very first line.)

Comment: I usually prefer setting the byte order mark. It does not work on #! scripts though.

Comment: @JanHudec Your preference is Wrong; BOMs are for UTF-16 and should be allowed to follow it to the dustbin of history.  UTF-8 isn't supposed to have them per some RFC whose number escapes me just now, and in any case, invisible magic is bad magic.

Comment: I know, but what RFCs say and what works in practice is not always coincident. Fact is that almost all editors recognize utf-8 "byte order mark" while vim and emacs and very few other recognize comments and they each recognize different comment though both emacs and vim format are recognized by python.